# Howto handle libxml2 parser errors

Tags: c, libxml2

I have to use xsd (schema) validation with libxml2, I can set a callback for error-handling, for the schema-validation errors, using: xmlSchemaSetValidErrors().

But before getting to the schema-validation, I have to parse my xml, to get a xmlDocPtr e.g. with xmlParseMemory. But: What if the xml is invalid, how do I set error-handlers for getting these errors? (I don't want them to be printed to stderr) I did not find a function similar to   xmlSchemaSetValidErrors for the parsing functions.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`xmlSetStructuredErrorFunc`](http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-xmlerror.html#xmlSetStructuredErrorFunc) and [`xmlSetGenericErrorFunc`](http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-xmlerror.html#xmlSetGenericErrorFunc).  These set error callbacks globally, because as you've noted, there won't be any xmlDocPtr context at this point.

http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-xmlerror.html

Comment: That answers my question, thank you Jason. I was confused by the description of those functions It says: "will be called for subsequent error messages while **not** parsing nor validating".

Comment: I believe (not 100% sure) that refers to situations where it has not yet gotten to parsing or validating, e.g. the file isn't found.