# How to make libxml2 not display connection errors?

Tags: c, libxml2

Consider the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <libxml/parser.h>
int main(void) {
    xmlDocPtr doc;
    xmlChar *s;
    doc = xmlParseFile("http://localhost:8000/sitemap.xml");
    s = xmlNodeGetContent((struct _xmlNode *)doc);
    printf("%s\n", s);
    return 0;
}
```

The output:

```
$ gcc -g3 -O0 $(xml2-config --cflags --libs) 1.c
$ ./a.out
error : Operation in progress
<result of xmlNodeGetContent>
```

That is, `xmlParseFile` produces undesired output. What happens here is `libxml2` tries to [translate](https://github.com/GNOME/libxml2/blob/v2.9.8/nanohttp.c#L1083) `localhost` to IP address. What it gets is `::1` and `127.0.0.1`. [`connect("[::1]:8000")`](https://github.com/GNOME/libxml2/blob/v2.9.8/nanohttp.c#L1113) results in [`EINPROGRESS`](https://github.com/GNOME/libxml2/blob/v2.9.8/nanohttp.c#L937) (since `libxml2` sets [`O_NONBLOCK`](https://github.com/GNOME/libxml2/blob/v2.9.8/nanohttp.c#L917) on the descriptor). So `libxml2` waits for it to [finish](https://github.com/GNOME/libxml2/blob/v2.9.8/nanohttp.c#L979), which results in `POLLOUT | POLLERR | POLLHUP`, and `libxml2` reports an [error](https://github.com/GNOME/libxml2/blob/v2.9.8/nanohttp.c#L1026).

Subsequent `connect("127.0.0.1:8000")` call succeeds, so all in all the program finishes successfully.

Is there a way to avoid this extra output?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Howto handle libxml2 parser errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15365451/howto-handle-libxml2-parser-errors)

Comment: @nwellnhof The error is produced not by parser, but solution is most likely as in the referenced question.

Comment: Yes, `xmlSetGenericErrorFunc` should also catch IO errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by nwellnhof, connection errors can be circumvented by setting error handler. Particularly, structured error handler, whatever that means.

While [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15365451/howto-handle-libxml2-parser-errors/15369407#15369407) in the other question more or less answers my question, that other question is about parser errors. And the answer doesn't provide example code. So,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <libxml/parser.h>

void structuredErrorFunc(void *userData, xmlErrorPtr error) {
    printf("xmlStructuredErrorFunc\n");
}

void genericErrorFunc(void *ctx, const char * msg, ...) {
    printf("xmlGenericErrorFunc\n");
}

int main(void) {
    xmlDocPtr doc;
    xmlChar *s;
    xmlSetGenericErrorFunc(NULL, genericErrorFunc);
    xmlSetStructuredErrorFunc(NULL, structuredErrorFunc);
    doc = xmlParseFile("http://localhost:8000/sitemap.xml");
    s = xmlNodeGetContent((struct _xmlNode *)doc);
    printf("%s\n", s);
    return 0;
}
```

This one outputs,

```
xmlStructuredErrorFunc
<result of xmlNodeGetContent>
```